# Help with DB2 Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I have the following query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYPROC( 
IN @TABLES VARCHAR(500)) 
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
LANGUAGE SQL 
SPECIFIC MYPROC
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
MODIFIES SQL DATA 
CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
BEGIN 

 --declare variables 

DECLARE @TABLE VARCHAR ( 100 ) ; 
DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR   
SELECT * FROM TABLE(split(@TABLES, ';')) AS FUNC; 

 -- create temp table 
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION . KEYS 
( 
    INMATEID INTEGER NOT NULL , 
    ROWID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 1 , INCREMENT BY 1 ) 
) 

WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED ; 

IF ( @INMATEID IS NOT NULL ) THEN 
    INSERT INTO SESSION . KEYS ( INMATEID ) VALUES ( @INMATEID ) ; 
ELSE 

    INSERT INTO SESSION . KEYS ( INMATEID ) 
    SELECT MyTable.ID
    FROM MYTABLE;
END IF ; 

 -- select tables 

OPEN C1;
FETCH C1 INTO @TABLE;

WHILE (SQLCODE = 0) DO
BEGIN

If (@TABLE = 'INMATES') THEN
   SELECT INMATES.* FROM ATABLE;  <-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM SPOT!
END IF;

FETCH C1 INTO @TABLE;
END;

END WHILE;
CLOSE C1;
END;
```

The problem is marked in the above procedure.  I want to loop through the passed in 'tables' and SELECT data from the tables that are passed in.  The problem is that I cannot do a SELECT statement within my while loop and if statement.  Are there any syntax problems that you see or is it something else entirely?

When I try to CREATE the procedure I get this error message:

```
SQL State: 42904
Vendor Code: -7032
Message: [SQL7032] SQL procedure, function, or trigger STSSP_JAILIF_GETDATA in PJGVDGD1 not created.
```

I've narrowed it down to that it's definitely related to my 'SELECT INMATES.*' line in the IF Statement.

Comment: missing semicolon after `SELECT INMATES.* FROM ATABLE`?

Comment: woops, just forgot it when transferring.  thanks Jack I put it back in the code.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you include the version of DB2 you are running and the platform it is running on.

Answer (score 3):

[The DB2 Docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/t0020511.html) suggest to me that returning a dynamic result set is done via a `cursor` with a `WITH RETURN` clause rather than a simple `select` statement.

Comment: I see, so is it not possible to loop through and return multiple SELECTS?

Comment: The way I read it you can return multiple sets by leaving more than 1 cursor open and setting `DYNAMIC RESULT SETS` to the maximum number of sets you anticipate returning?